# Count of activities per machine in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset:

```py
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
                      'machine':['A','A','A','B','B','A','B','B'],
                      'prod':['button','tack','pin','button','tack','pin','clip','clip'],
                      'qty':[100,50,30,70,60,15,200,180],
                      'hours':[4,3,1,3,2,0.5,5,6],
                      'day':[1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]})
my_df
    id  machine prod    qty hours   day
0   1   A       button  100 4.0     1
1   2   A       tack    50  3.0     1
2   3   A       pin     30  1.0     1
3   4   B       button  70  3.0     1
4   5   B       tack    60  2.0     1
5   6   A       pin     15  0.5     1
6   7   B       clip    200 5.0     2
7   8   B       clip    180 6.0     2
```

And I want to calculate the average production rate and the quantity of activities per machine. The first part is solved:

```py
my_df['prod_rate']=my_df['qty']/my_df['hours']
my_df
    id  machine prod    qty hours   day prod_rate
0   1   A   button      100 4.0     1   25.000000
1   2   A   tack        50  3.0     1   16.666667
2   3   A   pin         30  1.0     1   30.000000
3   4   B   button      70  3.0     1   23.333333
4   5   B   tack        60  2.0     1   30.000000
5   6   A   pin         15  0.5     1   30.000000
6   7   B   clip        200 5.0     2   40.000000
7   8   B   clip        180 6.0     2   30.000000
```

But for the second part I can't figure out how to solve it.

I tried this:

```
my_df['activities']=my_df.groupby(['day','machine'])['machine'].count()
```

It returns me this error: `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index`

This is the expected result:

```
    id  machine prod    qty hours   day prod_rate   activities
0   1   A   button      100 4.0     1   25.000000   4
1   2   A   tack        50  3.0     1   16.666667   4
2   3   A   pin         30  1.0     1   30.000000   4
3   4   B   button      70  3.0     1   23.333333   2
4   5   B   tack        60  2.0     1   30.000000   2
5   6   A   pin         15  0.5     1   30.000000   4
6   7   B   clip        200 5.0     2   40.000000   2
7   8   B   clip        180 6.0     2   30.000000   2
```

This means that the day 1 the quantity of machine activities of machine A was 4 and machine B was 2, and the day 2 the quantity of activities of machine B was 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.GroupBy.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) method aggregates the data, if you want to have as many rows as the input, use [`.GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) method instead:

```
my_df['activities'] = my_df.groupby(['day','machine'])['machine'].transform('count')
```

Comment: does `transform` act like a SQL window function then? I'm just curious.

Comment: I don't know, not an SQL expert ;)

Comment: No problem, considering this is a python question. Thank you very much for your time and answer @mozway! I'll investigate more on the `transform` method!. As soon as the system lets me, I'll accept your answer